# How to enable my modules in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I have create a module(person) in my Zend Project. Then created a controller(PersonController.php) in that module. Then created an action (addAction) in that controller. But when I use `http://myproject.dev/person/person/add` then it shows nothing.

`http://myproject.dev/` points to my zendproject's public folder therefore when I use `http://myproject.dev/` it shown me index page successfully. But it is not working with my modules.

I have seen somewhere that we have to configure **application.ini** and **Bootstrap.php** to tell the zend our module directory but I don't know how. What are these statements ??

My current directory is like this:

```
zendproject|
           |-> application 
                          |-> models
                          |-> modules
                                     |-> person
                                               |->controllers
                                                              |-> PersonController.php
```

Comment: did you use Zend_Tool to create the modules?

Comment: Yes I used Zend_Tool to create module,controller and even action.

Comment: What are your server configuration(s), for example LAMP/WAMP/Windows+IIS?

Comment: @Ozair: I am using Wamp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to do the next things:
1) application.ini

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

2) Create Bootstrap in each module:

```
class Person_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
}
```

Comment: It was typo in my question. My module folder is in zend's application folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply add module configuration below on your application.ini

```
resources.modules[] =
```

Just it.

Answer (score 2):

The code way to do it, within your Bootstrap, would be something like this:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
$frontController->returnResponse(true);
$frontController->setControllerDirectory(
            array(
                'default' => '/path/to/application/controllers',
                'person' => 'path/to/application/person/controllers'
            )
        );
$response = $frontController->dispatch();
$response->sendResponse();
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.front.html (in particular, look for the subheading 'setControllerDirectory() and addControllerDirectory')

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but i had to just add the line below only to get it to work properly:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```